# raspi-config does not allow me to select anything

Tags: raspi-config

I have configured my Raspberry Pi zero to have an ssh connection. When I log into that connection, I can access the terminal and all the commands I try work, except when I try to use `raspi-config`. It opens, and I can highlight one of the options and switch betwen the options, select, and finish, but I am unable to do anything beyond that. I have tried updating. How do I fix this, or is there some other thing I need to do other than press "enter" on select after I choose the option (I have also tried pressing enter over the option)?

Comment: did you run it as sudo?

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes, and I also tried it without, in which case it doesn't start.

Comment: `pressing enter over the option` - not sure what this means. Enter is on the keyboard, not on the screen

Comment: @JaromandaX I press right arrow or tab until the option is highlighted on the screen, then press ENTER.

Comment: OK, just looked like an odd statement ... what ssh client are you using? try using `ctrl`-`M` on your keyboard instead of enter, perhaps the ssh client is to blame

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using Microsoft's beta version that comes with Windows 10. `ctrl`-`M` also has no effect.

Comment: try putty or kitty - I wouldn't put much faith in the Win10 version (yet)

Comment: @JaromandaX It does appear windows is the problem. Putty seems to work.